# How to use Toggle Field Code to halve the "PAGE" & "NUMPAGES" variables - (Microsoft Word)

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, field-codes, footers

I want to have my footer count every second page

(so that when I print doubled sided paper, each sheet of paper will be counted as 1 page)

_

**Normally** page footers would look like; page 1, page 2, page 3, page 4, page 5

I have **different odd and even footers** so mine looks like; page 1, page 3, page 5

I want my footers to **increment every 2nd page** and look like; page 1, page 2, page 3

_

I was hoping that if I entered "Page {={PAGE/2}} of {={NUMPAGES/2}}" into the footer it would work but I can't seem to get around syntax errors or bookmark undefined errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you need is

```
Page {={PAGE}/2} of {={NUMPAGES}/2}
```

where *all* the {} are the special field brace pairs you can enter using cmd-F9 (or fn-cmd-F9 depending on your keyboard setup) on Mac Word.

It seems that you will always have an even number of pages, but if that is not the case you would have page numbers like 1.5, so you might need something like

```
Page {=INT(({PAGE}+MOD({PAGE},2))/2)} of {=INT(({NUMPAGES}+MOD({NUMPAGES},2))/2)}
```

There is probably a simpler way to do it.

Either way, bear in mind that modifying page numbers uses causes a problem with page numbering elsewhere, e.g. in Tables of Content.

Comment: Thanks heaps yokki, I really appreciate it. I didn't realize the brackets generated by CMD+F9 were different from the brackets that can be typed from the physical keyboard. The code looks simple enough to me, as long as the code gets the job done (which it does), I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Each calculation needs to be inside its own field (CTRL+F9 or CMD+F9 inserts the braces with two spaces between `{  }`)

`{ IF { =INT({ PAGE } /2) } = { =({ PAGE } /2) } { INT({ PAGE } /2 } }`

The outer field "IF" syntax: `{ IF A = B T }` where A, B, T are all fields.

A is the calculated field: `{ =INT(X /2) }`, B is the calculated field `{ =(X /2) }` (of course, X is the `{ PAGE }` field.)

T is the 'TRUE' condition, the calculated field: `{ =INT(X /2) }`

The 'FALSE' condition is null, so there will be nothing on odd pages.

Adding the NUMPAGES follows the same approach, but the T portion of the IF field needs to be included in quote marks:

`{ IF { =INT({ PAGE } /2) } = { =({ PAGE } /2) } "Page { INT({ PAGE } /2 } of { =INT({ NUMPAGES } /2) }" }`

Just happened to think ... if you want the footer on the *front* of the 2-sided print, substitute `({ PAGE } +1)` for each `{ PAGE }` field. Also, use `({NUMPAGES} +1)` instead of `{NUMPAGES}` so that odd-numbered totals round up (e.g., 5 or 6 pages reports 3 sheets, 7 or 8 pages reports 4 sheets, etc.).

Comment: Thanks heaps caskey, I really appreciate it. I didn't realize the brackets generated by CMD+F9 were different from the brackets that can be typed from the physical keyboard.

Comment: Can you answer the question in the following link? Thank you. https://superuser.com/questions/1647346/the-set-field-codes-in-ms-word-doesnt-run-correctly