# SET field codes in MS Word calculates a sum instead of keeping text

Tags: microsoft-word, equations, field-codes

For getting the result in Figure 1, I input the field codes in MS Word as Figure 2. However, the result shows as Figure 3. In fact, I want to **store** the result "1-3" in the bookmark xxx using the field code `SET`, and the "1-3" can be **updated dynamically**. Where is wrong? Why does the result come from subtracting 3 from 1? How to keep the form of "1-3"? How to edit the field codes? Thanks.

Figure1: Objective

[image]

Figure2: the field codes in MS Word

[image]

Figure3: the result displays

[image]

Comment: Using the StyleRef field inside a Set field is a bit problematic. The value of the bookmark should not change when the reference to the bookmark is in a different location, while the that of the styleref field should. In addition, you are getting the result from your calculation (=) field that I would expect. What is it you are trying to get with this? Would you want it to show "1-3" instead of -2?

Comment: @Charles Kenyon, Thank you. I want to store the result "1-3" to xxx, and refer to xxx in the future. In addition, the StyleRef field can be placed in a SET field. For example, if {SET xxx {={STYLEREF 1 \s}-{SEQ ( \* ARABIC \s 1}} } is changed to {SET xxx {={STYLEREF 1 \s}} }, the result of {REF xxx} will become to 1 from -2. I want to store the result of {STYLEREF 1 \s} and {SEQ ( \* ARABIC \s 1} into the xxx in a specified form such as "1-3", "1.3", and so on, not to calculate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I am unsure of the purpose of this.

Using the Set field gives you a bookmark. The contents of that bookmark are not dynamic. Neither the [SEQ field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields) nor the [StyleRef field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) will update when the bookmark is referenced. You will get the same result each time.

The [calculation/formula field (=)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-formula-field-32d5c9de-3516-4ec3-80ed-d1fc2b5bc21d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) calculates what is there. So 1-3 = -2. That is the expected result. You could use the Quote field to show the equation, but then used in the Set field, you still will get the same thing every time it is referenced.

This is shown in the [sample document. (temporary link)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8a4bg9rfbgyqyhe/deleteme%20styleref%20seq%202021-05-08.docx?dl=0)

[image: screenshot from sample]

### Consider AutoText or Building Blocks instead

If you are trying to re-use the formula `{ StyleRef 1 \s } - { Seq ( \s }` this would be best saved as AutoText and inserted into your document. You could use the AutoText field if you wanted. You can [attach a keyboard shortcut to AutoText](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330) for easy insertion. [Assign your AutoText entries to a key or key combination.](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#Key)

AutoText and other Building Blocks [can only be saved in templates](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks).

**Note:** links are to my website or pages I have written except the one about the calculation field.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly the answer I want. It's an incredible solution. Finally, can you recommend a book on field codes in MS Word? Thanks again.

Comment: My own page was linked in my answer. I know of no book devoted to fields. Chapter 21 of this book is very good: http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ISBN=0470591846/balancecheckbookA/ Fields are an old technology and anything from Word 97 on will be useful. However Paul Edstein has a number of very helpful tutorials: You can find them pinned to the top of this forum: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/

Comment: Thank you. Best wishes to you.

Comment: Stephanie Kruger's Advanced Office Documents book taught me everything I could want to know about content controls, and I am sure covered field codes as well (I am at work so I don't have my copy to hand)

Comment: @AdamV, Thank you. I have downloaded the Advanced Office Documents and her new update book: Documents, Presentations, and Workbooks.